# Python Load Arquivos Serialização

Tags: python, serialização, load, carregamento

Olá, estou estudando Python a algum tempo e fazendo alguns programas pra juntar com o Arduino.

Minha dúvida é em boas práticas no carregamento de arquivos.

Quero fazer um programa que interpreta arquivos. Minha ideia foi inspirada na lógica do HTML,CSS e SonicPI. Onde os arquivos são criados em qualquer editor.
Com isso fazer alterações no arquivo com as instâncias e outro programa lê e executa os códigos criados. Tal qual um editor HTML.

Já vi as formas de serialização: pickle, Shelve e Json. Não queria arquivos criptografados.

Porém o que mais fez o que gostaria é o exemplo abaixo com o exec e Garbage Collector.

Exemplo:

arquivo ArqInstancias.py

```
 pt1 = ponto('cor pt1')
 pt2 = ponto('cor pt2')
```

---

Programa que lê o arquivo ArqInstancias.py

```
import gc  

class ponto(object):
    def __init__(self,cor):
        self.cor = cor

exec(open("ArqInstancias.py").read())
   # execução e leitura

instancias = [i for i in gc.get_objects() if i.__class__ is ponto]
   # recebe as instancias da classe ponto

for i in range(len(instancias)):
    print(instancias[i].cor)
   # imprime o atributo cor de cada instancia.
```

---

saida / resultado:

```
cor pt1
cor pt2
```

E se eu chamar pt1.cor também tenho saída. Ou seja, essa instância foi incorporada ao programa.

Funcionar, funciona mas gostaria de saber se essa é uma boa prática ou se existe algum outro modo de fazer essa "importação de instâncias" sem criptografar o texto.

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito a sua necessidade, mas só de bater o olho me parece que a sua abordagem de executar um script externo é potencialmente insegura. Alguém com más intenções pode criar qualquer coisa que você vai executar sem saber... Se vc quer receber dados de pontos, não é mais fácil (e seguro) simplesmente ler um arquivo yaml, xml ou json, por exemplo? Todos esses são dados textuais abertos, e não são criptografados.

Comment: Olá chará obrigado. Entendi o risco dessa abordagem. Minha dúvida é se importando com xml, json se eu vou ter as instancias disponiveis na memória.

Comment: Meu objetivo é um programa que lê um arquivo, interpreta os dados e printa na tela. Ex: pt1(x,y). pt2(w,z) e quando eu abro no programa ele com o Tkinter mostra os pontos nas posições (x,y) e (w,z)
Mas não serão só pontos, são diversas classes com atributos distintos e variados

Comment: Ver mais exemplos de json e xml. mto obrigado!

Comment: Bom, json e xml não são criptografados porém tem uma organização bem própria. 
E criar/editar códigos no formato é complicado.
Pesquiso uma forma de incorporar as instâncias criadas como se tivesse digitado manualmente. 
Não sei se é viavel.

Comment: Ok. Bom, eu ofereci uma resposta que talvez te ajude. Dá uma olhada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, como eu disse, executar um script externo da forma como vc sugere é perigoso porque você não tem como saber o que tem lá pra ser executado.

Se a sua necessidade é só receber dados que sejam facilmente configuráveis (pelo usuário) em formato texto, que tal usar JSON por exemplo? Eis uma sugestão:

### Arquivo JSON de configuração

```
{
    "pontos" : [
        {
            "nome": "pt1",
            "cor": "black",
            "x": 10,
            "y": 20
        },
        {
            "nome": "pt2",
            "cor": "blue",
            "x": 43,
            "y": 68
        }
    ]
}
```

### Código que lê esse arquivo

```
import sys
import json

# ===================================
def main(args):
    """
    Entrada principal do programa.

    Parâmetros
    ----------
    args: lista
        Lista de argumentos recebidos na linha de comando. Não é utilizado.

    Retornos
    --------
    exitCode: int
        Código de saída do programa (que pode ser utilizado como errorlevel em
        chamadas no sistema operacional).
    """

    with open('ArqInstancias.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)

        pontos = data['pontos']
        for ponto in pontos:
            print('-' * 20)
            print('Nome do ponto: {}'.format(ponto['nome']))
            print('Cor do ponto: {}'.format(ponto['cor']))
            print('Coordenadas do ponto: ({:02d}, {:02d})'.format(ponto['x'], ponto['y']))
            print('-' * 20)

    return 0

# ===================================
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

### Saída desse programa

```
--------------------
Nome do ponto: pt1
Cor do ponto: black
Coordenadas do ponto: (10, 20)
--------------------
--------------------
Nome do ponto: pt2
Cor do ponto: blue
Coordenadas do ponto: (43, 68)
--------------------
```

Comment: Hunmnmn... cara mto obrigado, não é tão simples de criar mas acho que e a melhor forma mesmo.

Vendo identado dessa forma realmente não é tão complexo. Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Por que não é tão simples de criar? Qual é a dificuldade na criação? Não entendi.

Comment: vi uns exemplos sem identação... O SoniPI deve usar coisas parecidas. Porém é um programa beeem mais complexo e omite as chaves e marcações. porém deve ter um interpretador próprio para tal.

Comment: Indentação no JSON, vc diz? Não é um problema, desde que ele esteja no formato correto. A indentação é só para tornar mais fácil de ler para um humano, mas você pode tirar todos os newline e espaços e vai funcionar do mesmo jeito. Não entendi o que é "omite chaves e marcaçoes", e não sei o que é SoniPI, mas você não o havia mencionado. Se precisa fazer uma integração com esse tal de SoniPI, bom, então talvez você precise fazer no formato dele. Mas nada te impede de construir um conversor e manter a sua configuração como for mais fácil pra vc no dia-a-dia.

Comment: Se a sua "estranheza" (na falta de uma palavra melhor) é com a sintaxe do arquivo JSON, bom, talvez vc se dê melhor com o [YAML](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). A formatação dele é bem mais simples (até, pode-se argumentar, mais humanamente legível) e tem um pacote chamado PyYAML para sua leitura em Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866600/yaml-parsing-and-python

Comment: Outra coisa: se a resposta te ajudou, por favor [considere aceitá-la](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Comment: O SoniPI foi somente inspiração mesmo. Nele dá pra fazer live coding de música. Escreve no próprio editor do programa e o programa vai interpretando, continuamente. 
Meu intuito é fazer um live coding com luzes led. Não só live mas tb criar cenários e "animações". 
Nisso vou criar loops, linhas, figuras geométricas, adicionar efeitos e etc.